# Database Java Bean SQL Statement

Tags: java, jdbc

In my database bean I have a section of code which is below :

```
public Integer getTotalOrgPoints() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = ConnectionHandler.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_TOTAL_ORG_SCORE);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                totalOrgPoints = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return totalOrgPoints;
    }
```

For the statement `QUERY_TOTAL_ORG_SCORE` if I use

```sql
SELECT SUM(users.score) 
FROM   user_organisation_relationships 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON user_organisation_relationships.user_id = users.id 
WHERE  organisation_id = 1
```

It will return the value for that organisation but if I use

```sql
SELECT SUM(users.score) 
FROM   user_organisation_relationships 
       INNER JOIN users 
               ON user_organisation_relationships.user_id = users.id 
WHERE  organisation_id = ?
```

I get nothing does anyone know why this is happening for me?.

Comment: you don't bind value for `?`, you don't close resultset, statement and connection

Comment: [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: You need to review `PreparedStatement` interface.

Comment: And, you need to review your exception handling approach too. Right now, the code is just blindly continuing as if nothing exceptional happened.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to bind values for prepared statement before `executequery`

```
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
```

Modified:-

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ConnectionHandler.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_TOTAL_ORG_SCORE);
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```